# Unit testing a debounce function to see if timer times out after 500ms

Tags: javascript, jestjs

```
  export const debounce = (func: (arg?: any) => void, timeOut: number = 500) => {
      let timer: ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>;
      return function(...args: any) {
        if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(func, timeOut, ...args);
      };
    };
```

I am trying to create a simple test for this debounce function. How do i begin this?

Comment: your question is very broad so far. could you narrow it to one specific thing? what to test? how to mock timer? how to ensure callback passed in has been finally called or not?

Comment: I need to test if the timer is timing out after 500 ms.

Answer (score 0):

We can mock timers with [`jest.useFakeTimers();`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/timer-mocks)

The we could ensure our function is called only after timeout passed:

```
jest.useFakeTimers();

it('calls function after 500ms if timeout not been specified', () => {
  const callback = jest.fn();
  const debounced = debounce(callback);
  debounced();
  expect(callback).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  jest.advanceTimersByTime(499);
  expect(callback).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  jest.advanceTimersByTime(2);
  expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Additionally you may want to check if underlying function gets the same arguments you've passed to debounced version

```
it('passes same arguments down to callback', () => {
  const callback = jest.fn();
  const debounced = debounce(callback, 1);
  debounced(1, 'a');
  jest.advanceTimersByTime(2);
  expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1, 'a');
});
```

that sequential calls shifts callback execution:

```
it('each call delay execution for specified timeout', () => {
  const callback = jest.fn();
  const debounced = debounce(callback, 50);
  debounced();
  jest.advanceTimersByTime(49);
  debounced();
  expect(callback).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  jest.advanceTimersByTime(49);
  expect(callback).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  jest.advanceTimersByTime(2);
  expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```